# Simple PHP string parsing

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to parse the following format with PHP:

```
// This is a comment
{
this is an entry
}
{
this is another entry
}
{
entry
{entry within entry}
{entry within entry}
}
```

Maybe is just the lack of caffeine, but i can't think of a decent way of getting the contents of the curly braces.

Comment: No way to accurately get content like that.  You need better delimiters.  But if you really REALLY wanna try, you need to basically write an algorithm that works from the outside in, instead of top to bottom.

Comment: The nested *entry* is the pain point.

Comment: You could add a `<?php` at the top and `token_get_all()`. Iterate through, skipping the `<?php` and any comment token. Then join the keywords together with `join()`.

Comment: this is similar to RTF group levels, there every { and } causes a group level index to increase / decrease, so the reader knows which level the characters are in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a common parsing task, basically you need to keep track of the various states you can be in and use a combination of constants and function calls to maintain them.

Here is some rather inelegant code that does just that:

```
<?php

$input = file_get_contents('input.txt');

define('STATE_CDATA', 0);
define('STATE_COMMENT', 1);

function parseBrace($input, &$i)
{
    $parsed = array(
        'cdata' => '',
        'children' => array()
    );
    $length = strlen($input);
    $state = STATE_CDATA;
    for(++$i; $i < $length; ++$i) {
        switch($input[$i]) {
            case '/':
                if ('/' === $input[$i+1]) {
                    $state = STATE_COMMENT;
                    ++$i;
                } if (STATE_CDATA === $state) {
                    $parsed['cdata'] .= $input[$i];
                }
                break;
            case '{':
                if (STATE_CDATA === $state) {
                    $parsed['children'][] = parseBrace($input, $i);
                }
                break;
            case '}':
                if (STATE_CDATA === $state) {
                    break 2; // for
                }
                break;
            case "\n":
                if (STATE_CDATA === $state) {
                    $parsed['cdata'] .= $input[$i];
                }
                $state = STATE_CDATA;
                break;
            default:
                if (STATE_CDATA === $state) {
                    $parsed['cdata'] .= $input[$i];
                }
        }
    }
    return $parsed;
}

function parseInput($input)
{
    $parsed = array(
        'cdata' => '',
        'children' => array()
    );
    $state = STATE_CDATA;
    $length = strlen($input);
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
        switch($input[$i]) {
            case '/':
                if ('/' === $input[$i+1]) {
                    $state = STATE_COMMENT;
                    ++$i;
                } if (STATE_CDATA === $state) {
                    $parsed['cdata'] .= $input[$i];
                }
                break;
            case '{':
                if (STATE_CDATA === $state) {
                    $parsed['children'][] = parseBrace($input, $i);
                }
                break;
            case "\n":
                if (STATE_CDATA === $state) {
                    $parsed['cdata'] .= $input[$i];
                }
                $state = STATE_CDATA;
                break;
            default:
                if (STATE_CDATA === $state) {
                    $parsed['cdata'] .= $input[$i];
                }
        }
    }
    return $parsed;
}

print_r(parseInput($input));
```

This produces the following output:

```
Array
(
    [cdata] =>




    [children] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [cdata] =>
this is an entry

            [children] => Array
            (
            )

        )

        [1] => Array
        (
            [cdata] =>
this is another entry

            [children] => Array
            (
            )   

        )

        [2] => Array
        (
            [cdata] => 
entry



            [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [cdata] => entry within entry
                    [children] => Array
                    (
                    )


                )

                [1] => Array
                (
                    [cdata] => entry within entry
                    [children] => Array
                    (
                    )

                )

            )

        )

    )

)
```

You'll probably want to clean up all the whitespace but some well placed trim's will sort that for you.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution for large amount of content, but it works.

```
<?php
        $text = "I am out of the brackets {hi i am in the brackets} Back out { Back in}";
        print $text . '<hr />';

        $tmp = explode("{",$text);
        $tmp2 = array();
        $wantedText = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp); $i++){
                if(stristr($tmp[$i],"}")){
                    $tmp2 = explode("}",$tmp[$i]);
                    array_push($wantedText,$tmp2[0]);
                }
        }
        print_r($wantedText);
    ?>
```

Results:

```
Array ( [0] => hi i am in the brackets [1] => Back in )
```

Comment: Well, for the most part, if you want to get into nested brackets, just expand it into a function that can recall upon itself or something similar.